# Using a UISlider to change a CGFloat or similar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Allright, I'm completely new to programming but I feel I am picking it up quite quickly, I've gone straight into Objective-C and I know some would say that wasn't wise but anyway.

Heres the sitch, In my ViewController.m I have:

```
@implementation ViewController

CGPoint Destination;  --->irrelevant for this question just giving a layout
CGFloat xamt, yamt;  ---> irrelevant for this question just giving a layout
CGFloat speed = 30;
```

so my question is, How/where would I put code to get a UISlider to change the speed value?

Comment: Seriously: Get a book. The Big Nerd Ranch guides are very, very good, very beginner-friendly, well written, and soon you won't be a beginner anymore. This kind of question is also easily solvable by just looking at the documentary of UISlider (in Xcode, open the Organizer window to browse the docs).

Comment: @fzwo Will check the book you recommended, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate an `UISlider` and add it to one of the views that are currently displayed (I'll assume you use a view controller, and it is `self`):

```
UISlider *s = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 280, 44)];
[s addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:s];
[s release];
```

Then implement the slider's action method (still in your view controller's class):

```
- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)s
{
    speed = 30 * s.value;
}
```

Hope this helps.

P.s. : good advice: seriously, learn C first and master it before doing serious Objective-C or you'll get confused later or sooner, and wasting your users' RAM is not fun :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I will give this a go and see what I can tweak, and yeh I figured it is the Best thing to do, I have some C++ For Beginners books which I will eventually read up On, Cheers for this!

Comment: FWIW, I disagree on the need to learn C (or C++) first. They follow a completely different programming paradigm and are IMHO much harder to pick up than Objective-C, which has much more in common with Snalltalk than with its technical basis C. In any case, it is perfectly possible to learn objective-C without learning C first, and then learn C when (if) it becomes necessary. Don't confuse both languages - they are *very* different.

Comment: @H2CO3, im having a little difficulty implementing your provided code, Under what class do I provide your first given code, Also should I add it to the .h or .m (This is how you can tell I'm a beginner

Comment: @fzwo Thanks for the added advice, you have been helpful

Comment: @fzwo Of course in the implementation (.m). And I was assuming you use a view controller, add that code in there.